# I use Spring+MongoDB,when i execute a query method,it throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.MongoException$DuplicateKey

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

There's mongodb's jar in my classpath.
Someone can help me?

configuration:
    
        
        
    
    </mongo:mongo>-->

code:

```
List<GeoLocation> serarchNear(double lat, double lng, double maxDistance, int maxCount) {
   try {
       Point point = new Point(lng, lat);
       Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("loc").near(point).maxDistance(maxDistance));
       query.limit(maxCount);

       List<GeoLocation> find = template.find(query, GeoLocation.class);

       return find;
   } catch (Exception e) {
       return null;
   }
}
```

exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.MongoException$DuplicateKey
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using mongo driver version 2.x instead of 3.x(if you are using it currently).